# Change default encoding only for printing

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, printing

Is there a way, I can change the default encoding in python **only for printing**?
Can the behaviour of the `print` statement be changed in general?
I don't want to do it with `sys.setdefaultencoding()`, because this would change it for the whole script, but I don't know if every module I use supports unicode... 
I know I could do it with `print u'äöü'.encode('utf-8')` but it would be awful to use it everytime...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't think you can do it just *for printing* (using `print` explicitly), you probably can accomplish what you want using

`sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout)`

This changes the encoding for all "normal" program output. If you're not familiar with them, you may want to read [this article on standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)